# How to get an url with username as slug parameter django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, api, django-rest-framework

I have a balance model with onetoone field with Users models, so every user have a "balance" relationated with themselves. This is my model:

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_balance(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        Saldos.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
        print('created balance model to user')
```

This is my Serializer

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class OwnerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']

class BalanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = OwnerSerializer(read_only=True)    

    class Meta:
        model = Balance
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is my view

```
from .models import Balance
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import BalanceSerializer

class BalanceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Balance.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BalanceSerializer
```

And this is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import BalanceViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'api/balance', BalanceViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

This works fine, problem is that i'd like to the url for every single user be something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/balance/username instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/balance/1

Is there any way to put the username that is related that balance in url?

Comment: in `BalanceSerializer` you are using model `Saldos`, where it is comes from ?

Comment: @Md.TanvirRaihan Oh, it should be model Balance, sorry for that i just edited

Answer (score 0):

You can add StringRelatedField in your serializer:

```
username = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='user', read_only=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that i'd like to have urls like http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/balance/username instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/balance/1, knowing that username field is obviously in the User auth model and Balance model is OneToOneField with User

Comment: I think you are looking for "lookup_field = slug "

Answer (score 0):

Add a `slug` field in your `Balance` model,

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    .....
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True) # make it unique
```

**run migration command.**

then in `BalanceSerializer`,

```
class BalanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = OwnerSerializer(read_only=True)    

    class Meta:
        model = Balance
        fields = '__all__'
        lookup_field = 'slug'
```

and then in your view,

```
class BalanceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):    
    queryset = Balance.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BalanceSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

now try http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/balance/your-slug

**NOTE**: I don't test it in my local, but it should work.

Comment: Yeah, i though this as a possible solution, but then i should be add the slug manually for everyuser, this could be a nice solution if there was a way to set the slug field as the same as the user username by default

Comment: You can override the `.save()` method and then create a slug using your username. Then you don't need to add the slug manually.